# IF/Case statement when using SparkSQL with Cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am trying to transform data when selecting from Cassandra to Spark using Scala.

When selecting data I would like to transform the data to place the counts into a specific count_* column based on the value.

I am unable to find an IF/CASE statement to use with Spark SQL. Any ideas?

```
val results = csc.sql("
    SELECT trip_sell_key, trip_veh_key, idle_stop_date, COUNT(*),
    SUM (case when idle_stop_duration >= 0  
    and idle_stop_duration < 5 then  1 else 0 end)
    from veh_trip"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure your SQL is valid for SparkSQL. Don't remember if SparkSQL does support `case else` statements.

Another point is that `COUNT(*)` and  `SUM(...)` are aggregation functions and they can only work in conjunction with a `GROUP BY` clause, which is missing in your statement